# Could not validate app name Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, web

I'm new to MS Azure.
I've created a trial account but when trying to create a new Web App, both through the web portal and through VS2017, I'm getting the "Could not validate app name
".

1. I'm sure the name I'm giving is unique.
2. I've tried cleaning out cache\signing out and in etc.

What am I missing?
Thanks!

[Exmaple #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPm2D.png)
[Example #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEL95.png)

Comment: can you paste a screen shot?

Comment: stackoverflow is not letting me embed them, but they're in the links above

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are not hosting your web-app service in this outage affected region. Right now there is an outage going on with DNS name resolution as mentioned below

**[Regions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/#current)**

Comment: @DavidMakogon why it should not be posted as an answer? how would others know if they come across the same issue? there are many questions as such! i dont see any reason for downvoting

Comment: do you think all the questions posted here on SO are related to programming?

Comment: No i am not arguing , just wanted to get a clear idea so that i don't repeat. Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

This issue can occur if you have selected an incorrect subscription in the drop down list below the app name input box. Select an active subscription and see if this resolves your issue.